# SocketCluster - How can I pass the Worker files variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am using SocketCluster for the backend of something I am building.

It is recommended to not have Business logic in the initial 'server.js' file that calls a 'New SocketCluster' but instead placing your logic etc in the Worker file to allow for multiple workers to be instantiated.

How would I pass variables to those 'worker' files?

If I wanted to use a randomly generated Id I cannot generate it in the worker file because it will be different for each Worker..hence wanting to pass the 'Worker' variables.

The standard approach to start a SocketCluster is something along the lines of:

```
var socketCluster = new SocketCluster({
  workers: 2, // May use 'numCPUs',
  brokers:  1,
  port: 3000,
  authKey: 'todo',
  appName: serverAppId,
  workerController: __dirname + '/app/worker.js',
  brokerController: __dirname + '/app/broker.js',
  socketChannelLimit: 100,
  rebootWorkerOnCrash: false,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  pingInterval: 2000
});
```

So based on that, how do I pass the Worker.js (or Broker.js) variables?  I wanted to send about 5 variables...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again.

Comment: what do you mean by variables?  Do you want them to all be instantiated with certain values?  Or do you want a value that's persisted across all of the workers even after it might be changed on a worker?